# Does anyone know how to make an expanding smoke with an almost "tendril-like" appearance?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm working on a cover for my book and I can't figure out how to make the smoke shape into "tendrils". I know how to do it with hair but with smoke; not so much. Please help and be as detailed as possible or I won't be able to follow. Thanks[image: ![(This is the closest picture to what I want to make)]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8YPd.jpg)

Comment: can you [edit] your question and add a reference image that illustrates what you are after?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with the smoke system. but maybe you can fake it with a curve/tendril mesh that is set to invisible and emits smoke (particles).

Comment: Is this is what you are looking for: http://recordit.co/rS4jbEnPtN?

Comment: sure cegaton, im still a noob with blender and i just learned how to make armatures move so im confused demons fate, and not really but nice try lukeD. ill post a picture of what i want if i can find the one that inspired me. i found it last year and thats how long ive been trying to make it.

Comment: https://cdn-images.xda-developers.com/direct/1/3/4/6/5/9/8/Biohazard.jpg for those of you who couldn't view it, this is the picture, but I'm looking for more pronounced tendrils.